# containerized Azure TTS supporting list TTS voices

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Will the Containerized Azure TTS add support for voice list to determine what is installed on a host? Matching the Azure list would be useful operationally plus for development and demos. Using "docker images" is a temp workaround.

`curl http://localhost:5000/cognitiveservices/voices/list`

Answer (score 0):

which container do you use?

in current container design, it has only one voice in one container

so in your deployment environment, you could use a list to track which is installed.

does this help?

Comment: To confirm I understand...
1. each voice is a separate container (e.g. es-mx-raul-apollo, en-us-zirarus) 
2. so, to run multiple voices/languages on the same hosts requires starting up multiple containers
3. each container will be on a separate port number (e.g. 5000, 5001)
4. the REST API for the container does not self-identify the voice/language
5. so, the client (or some middle layer) will need to map from voice to port number

Adding some kind of self-description to the /ready or /status would make middleware possible without knowing the docker details. 
Possible?

Comment: right.  you can use a middle layer to do the mapping for now